# Install iPython3 notebook Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.x, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm having trouble installing ipython3 notebook in Ubuntu 14.04

### pip3 install :

```
vco@geoHP:~/Programming/python/BrandonRhodes/pycon-pandas-tutorial-1.0$ pip3 install --user ipython[notebook]
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): ipython[notebook] in /home/vco/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages
  Installing extra requirements: 'notebook'
Cleaning up...
vco@geoHP:~/Programming/python/BrandonRhodes/pycon-pandas-tutorial-1.0$
```

upgrading iPython notebook :

```
vco@geoHP:~/Programming/python/BrandonRhodes/pycon-pandas-tutorial-1.0$ pip3 install --user "ipython[all]"
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): ipython[all] in /home/vco/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages
  Installing extra requirements: 'all'
Cleaning up...
```

Trying to run notebook

```
vco@geoHP:~/Programming/python/BrandonRhodes/pycon-pandas-tutorial-1.0$ ipython notebook
-bash: /usr/bin/ipython: No such file or directory
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here

I can use the version from the Ubuntu repo - but that is for Python 2. If I try and run the file that I want to work on ([link to file](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10999391/)) it gives me an error about JSON 3 instead of 4.

Since trying to run that file I've removed ipython from the system with `sudo apt-remove ipython` and reinstalled using `pip3`.

cheers

Comment: Try opening a new terminal - it looks like it may have cached the path. If it can't find it, ensure that `/home/vco/.local/bin` is on $PATH.

Comment: hey @ThomasK you're right - if I run it from the path that it's in (`~/.local/bin`) it works fine (python 3 version) so I can just make a bash alias for that I guess... cheers :)

Comment: Or you can add it to `$PATH` in `~/.bashrc` - `export PATH="/home/vco/.local/bin:$PATH`. That way it works for anything you pip install with `--user`.

Comment: Is it that you are missing sudo - sudo pip install etc...? I got it installed easy using Anaconda (worth checking out) which was just a straight download.

Comment: Sudo pip is a no no :)